# How to convert String into key/value pair(map) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, key-value

I'm trying to convert simple string which is nothing but xml data format into key/value pair.

```
input :-> str ='<name>xyz</name>'

output :-> {name : 'xyz'}
```

below are the myFunction but it's not showing exact outcomes

```
let str = '<name>xyz</name>'

function myFunction(str) {

    let map ={}
    let key 
    let value

    str = str.split(/[.:;?!~,`"&|()<>{}[\]\r\n/\\]+/)

    str = _.compact(str)
    key = ??
    value = ??

 return map    

}
```

Basically anything inside <> would be key and between closing tag would be output.I'm lacking proper logic here. Any help would be appreciable :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match whatever's between the first `<` to `>` to match the key, and match whatever's between the first `>` and second `<` to the value, then make an object out of it:

```js
const str = '<name>xyz</name>';
const [,key,val] = str.match(/<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</);
const obj = { [key]: val };
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Huh, [es6 computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)...how had I missed that until now?